# Cleaning up current page URL in browser

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple redirecting and content loading system using PHP `$_GET[''];` variable on the URL. This is kind of working for me when for example I have

```
www.domain.com/product.php?sku=100
&
www.domain.com/product.php?type=entertainment
```

but in case of haveing some dummy inputs like

```
www.domain.com/product.php?
Or
www.domain.com/product.php?type=
Or
www.domain.com/product.php?sku=
www.domain.com/product.php?typeentertainment
```

How can I clean up the URL to looks like

```
www.domain.com/product.php
```

and load the `all.php` to the page? How can I fix this issue?

```
<?PHP
 if(isset($_GET['sku']) && $_GET['sku']!=""){
  $sku = $_GET['sku'];   
  require_once(__ROOT__.'/sku.php');
}
 elseif(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']!=""){
  $type = $_GET['type'];     
  require_once(__ROOT__.'/type.php');
}
else{
  require_once(__ROOT__.'/all.php');
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking? Are you wanting to redirect all those _"dummy input"_ URLs to `/product.php` so that the URL actually changes in the browser address bar?

Comment: Also, I recommend `!empty($_GET['whatever'])` as an alternative to `isset($_GET['whatever']) && $_GET['whatever'] != ""`

Comment: Hi and thanks for comment Phil but my problem is when the URL is not empty! and there is some junk strings there. if some wants to bookmark the page ! how can I clean up the URL? I tried to redirect the page to clean URL but it is not working

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61355690/edit) and add details about what you've tried. Also explain what you expect to happen vs what actually happens. If you're receiving any error messages, please include those too.

Comment: but I think I already explained this on second and third Paragraph with example of dummy inputs

Comment: You said _"I tried to redirect the page to clean URL but it is not working"_ but I can't see that anywhere in your question, nor have you explained how it is _"not working"_